# flutter_background_service_android Plugin Throws Exception in Android Devices

Tags: flutter, android-service, background-service, foreground-service, flutter-background

I am currently working on a Flutter application that utilizes the flutter_background_service package for running background services. To implement the background service, I have integrated the flutter_background_service_android package. However, I am encountering an issue where the background service is not working as expected on Android devices.

The error message I am getting is:

```
flutter_background_service_android threw an error: Exception: This class should only be used in the main isolate (UI App). The app may not function as expected until you remove this plugin from pubspec.yaml
```

following is the code for my background service (my_background_service.dart)

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service_android/flutter_background_service_android.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '/helper/my_helper/socket_io_helper.dart';
import '/helper/my_helper/my_get_di.dart' as my_di;

/// Initialization of the Background Service
Future<void> initializeBackgroundService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  /// OPTIONAL, using custom notification channel id
  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'my_foreground',
    'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
    importance: Importance.low,
  );

  /// Object of the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  /// Initialize settings
  if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_bg_service_small'),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Create android notification channel
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  /// Configuration of the Background Service
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
      notificationChannelId: 'my_foreground',
      initialNotificationTitle: 'AWESOME SERVICE',
      initialNotificationContent: 'Initializing',
      foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
      onBackground: onIosBackground,
    ),
  );

  /// Starting the background service after doing the configurations
  service.startService();
}

// DOLATER: Handle the iOS Background Task Here
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<bool> onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  return true;
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  /// OPTIONAL when use custom notification
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  /// My instances
  SocketIoHelper socketIoHelper = SocketIoHelper();

  /// Executed when the app is in the foreground
  service.on('loginSuccess').listen((event) async {
    /// Creating a socket.io client
    await my_di.init();
    await socketIoHelper.initializeAwesomeNotification();
    await socketIoHelper.initializeMsgService();
    await socketIoHelper.createTopics();
  });
  service.on('containsTheTopics').listen((event) async {
    await socketIoHelper.joinCallInitializationTopic();
    await socketIoHelper.listenCallInitializationTopic();
    await socketIoHelper.listenCallRecieveTopic();
  });

  /// Executed when the app is in the background
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final plusRemovedPhoneNumberFromLocal =
      prefs.getString("plusRemovedPhoneNumber") ?? "";

  /// Creating a socket.io client
  if (plusRemovedPhoneNumberFromLocal != "") {
    await my_di.init();
    await socketIoHelper.initializeAwesomeNotification();
    await socketIoHelper.initializeMsgService();
    await socketIoHelper.joinCallInitializationTopic();
    await socketIoHelper.listenCallInitializationTopic();
    await socketIoHelper.listenCallRecieveTopic();
  }

  /// Update the background service timer
  /// And show it as a foreground notification
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          888,
          'COOL SERVICE',
          'Awesome ${DateTime.now()}',
          const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'my_foreground',
              'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
              icon: 'ic_bg_service_small',
              ongoing: true,
            ),
          ),
        );

        /// if you don't using custom notification, uncomment this
        service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
          title: "My Service",
          content: "",
        );
      }
    }

    /// Printing background service timer in the flutter terminal
    print(
        " Background Service ====> ${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now())} ");
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I am also facing same issue but if I remove `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();` from onstart() then i get no errors. But i'm not sure what would be the implications of these change.

Comment: that's true @yash, I also commented out the `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();` from onstart() and the error stopped appearing. Currently looking into the implications of this